# Data Driven Test - Protractor

Tags: angularjs, json, data-driven-tests

I want is  to edit a profile details with passing data from a json file.

Data Form having:

```
-First Name
-Last Name
-Current Password
-New Password
-Confirm Password, etc....
```

I need to change only Last Name. How can I do?

--Edited--

["This is the form which I have to edit."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLdky.jpg)

I need to change Only the Last name, First name should be the same. I'm passing values through json file.

```js
[
  {
    "fname":"" ,
    "lname":"",
    "currentpassword":"",
    "newpassword":"",
    "confirmpassword":""
  }
]
```

And this is the code :

```js
//import login details
var testData = require('./login_details.json');

//import editprofiledata
var editData = require('./editprofiledata.json');

describe ('Edit Profile Test', function(){

    //browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    browser.get("http://example");

    testData.forEach (function (data) {
        it ('Login to the system, and redirect to the dashboard', function() {
            element(by.name('email')).clear().sendKeys(data.Email);
            element(by.name('password')).clear().sendKeys(data.Password);

            //**click on Login button**//
            element(by.css('[ng-disabled="register.$invalid"]')).click();

            //**popup message click**//
            element(by.css('[ng-click="tapToast()"]')).click();
        });
    });

         it("redirect to the Edit Profile",function () {
            
             element(by.css('[ng-click="profileView()"]')).click();

             element(by.css('[ng-click = "goToEditView(2)"]')).click();

             browser.sleep(500);
         });

    editData.forEach (function (data) {
        it("changing details", function () {

            element(by.name('fname')).clear().sendKeys(data.fname);
            element(by.name('lname')).clear().sendKeys(data.lname);
            browser.sleep(1000);
            element(by.model('userEdit.currentPassword')).clear().sendKeys(data.currentpassword);
            browser.sleep(1000);
            element(by.model('userEdit.password')).clear().sendKeys(data.newpassword);
            browser.sleep(1000);
            element(by.model('userEdit.confirmPassword')).clear().sendKeys(data.confirmpassword);
            browser.sleep(1000);

element(by.css('[ng-click="editUserProfile(userEdit)"]')).click();
            browser.sleep(2000);
        });
    });
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried so far and exactly at what step you are facing issues?That would be far easier for someone to help you at that stage..

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I added more details. Please look into this.

Comment: still unclear. where is the code???

Comment: @VishalAggarwal code added

Answer (score 1):

Not so clear question but I guess you are thinking about some data provider like:

[jasmine-data-provider](http://moduscreate.com/protractor-and-jasmine-data-provider-write-once-test-many/)

Comment: I added more details. please look into this

Comment: So you answered an unclear question instead of using your privilege to flag it as unclear?